# Error exceeded disk quota despite the fact that they are disabled, and disk space is enough

Tags: centos, quota

On CentOS has recently started to happen a strange thing - the user can not create files in its directory:
[Deployer @ server ~] $ echo test> test.file 
-Bash: echo: write error: Disk quota exceeded

Although quotas had not been established:
[Deployer @ server ~] $ quota 
Disk quotas for user deployer (uid 500): none

Disk space is sufficient: 
[Deployer @ server ~] $ df-h 
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/ Dev / vzfs 9.6G 6.9G 2.8G 72% / 
none 256M 4.0K 256M 1% / dev

Problems with inodes should not be: 
[Deployer @ server ~] $ df-i 
Filesystem Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on 
/ Dev / vzfs 10000000 130959 9869041 2% / 
none 65536 95 65441 1% / dev

Can you please tell what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have group quota also enabled for that user:

```
repquota -avug|grep username
repquota -avug|grep groupname
```

Edit quota for group:

```
edquota -g groupname
```