# Quota exceeded after reboot (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, quota

System is Ubuntu 11.04.

Server is located at a IDC, and today they had some problems which led to server being rebooted.

Uploading files doesn't work now, and I tried creating files with vim/nano/pico, everything gives me error: ERROR WRITING: DISK QUOTA EXCEEDED

Now, how can that be? The user is setup with virtualmin and the user has UNLIMITED storage.
I tested with deleting a 10gb backup file, which didn't help.

All partitions have 0-9% usage.

Any help in resolving the matter is appreciated.

df -h:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             443G   11G  410G   3% /
none                  7.9G  196K  7.9G   1% /dev
none                  7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
none                  7.9G  120K  7.9G   1% /var/run
none                  7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /var/lock
/dev/sdb1             917G   74G  797G   9% /home
```

df -i:

```
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            29483008  532200 28950808    2% /
none                 2055317     781 2054536    1% /dev
none                 2057206       1 2057205    1% /dev/shm 
none                 2057206      54 2057152    1% /var/run
none                 2057206       5 2057201    1% /var/lock
/dev/sdb1            61054976  653042 60401934    2% /home
```

quota -v:

```
Disk quotas for user myuser (uid 1069):

 Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
 /dev/sdb1 9855440       0       0           86653       0       0
```

Comment: What `df -h` and `df -i` and `quota -v` are outputting?

Comment: What about `repquota -v -a`; however, it is the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed.

It was a group quota problem.

quotaoff -g /dev/sdb1 (which holds my home directories) turned off all group quotas.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806028/error-exceeded-disk-quota-despite-the-fact-that-they-are-disabled-and-disk-spac) pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: In case you cannot change the quota.
`du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h`

use this command in the home directory(e.g. `/usr2`) to check which folders are taking up space. 

You can also check if there are package cache. It can be safely removed